# dataset.collectAsList() causes java.lang.ClassCastException in cluster

Tags: apache-spark, user-defined-functions, apache-spark-dataset

When I do the `List<Row> rows = (List<Row>) dataset.collectAsList();` in Local using IntelliJ I get results but when run in Cluster I get this below error.
I am using UDF's in the Code

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2287)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1417)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2292)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2286)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2210)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2068)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1572)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:430)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy.readObject(List.scala:490)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor8.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Any idea? or any extra details required ?
Here is the schema

```
StructType(StructField(Mar,StringType,false),
 StructField(DY,StringType,false),
 StructField(MB,StringType,false),
 StructField(Med,StringType,false),
 StructField(DS,StringType,false),
 StructField(dist,StringType,false),
 StructField(DL,DecimalType(36,2),false),
 StructField(GP28,IntegerType,false),
 StructField(GPHH,IntegerType,false),
 StructField(CP28,IntegerType,false),
 StructField(CPHH,IntegerType,false),
 StructField(I28,LongType,false),
 StructField(IHH,LongType,false),
 StructField(U28,IntegerType,false),
 StructField(UHH,IntegerType,false))
```

Comment: What is the schema of the dataset?

Comment: Also, are you running it in a cluster or from let's say Intellj?

Comment: @LizardKing added schema

Comment: Happens in cluster only

Comment: Hi, In my case dataset.collectAsList() is giving IllegalArgumentException when running via Intellij. Does anyone know possible reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it happens only in the cluster my guess is that you are having issues with the classloader. It may be related to not having the dependencies marked as provided and ending up loading Spark code within your application causing class mismatch. Have a look at these spark issues [SPARK-9219](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-9219), and if you are using UDF look at [SPARK-18074](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18074).

Answer (score -1):

Your are trying to convert List MapPartitionsRDD so thats the problem.Its saying in your error.